# JetBrain IDE Golang

Tags: golang, ide, jetbrains

Добрый день в понедельник настал судный день , когда обновили данное чудо до новой версии. 
И появилась одна очень раздражительная проблема. 
Это папки vendor.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходя из выше приведенного оно распознает мои файлы как отдельную внешнюю библиотеку.

До обновления все было отлично , поставил я обнову а тут вот такое чудо. И когда пытаешься что-то поменять в своих родных файлах то вылазит такое вот окошко.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ну нажимаю я поменять везде.

Но есть жирный минус.

Наведу пример если удалить один импорт , оно даже не подсветит ни одной ошибки. Если поменять тип возвращаемых данных. Оно как ни странно ни одной ошибки не поменяет. Короче оно ведет себя как обычный текстовой редактор.

Помогите решить проблему , в старой версии все работало отлично.

Проблема наблюдается у сотрудников на MacOS и Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Думаю вам нужно настроить какие директории относятся к проекту, в настройках есть пункт Directories и получается у вас все vendor папки попали в раздел excluded, сам пользуюсь PhpStorm, такой проблемы не было.

Comment: @Yaroslav Molchan Так в том и дело что у меня тоже небыло таких проблем до обновы. Я уже все пробовал. Но увы это не помогло. Есть костыльные методы которые решают даную проблему на 80% но это костыли.

Comment: @Zaazik У этой IDE еще нет стабильной версии, есть лишь Preview. Она еще в разработке, поэтому такие "фокусы" возможны. Лучше такие вопросы адресовать им в саппорт.

Comment: @mit стабильная версия уже вышла. Так что скоро пора платить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я считаю что это следование особенностям языка Go: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories

папки vendor и internal имеют в go особое значение. В частности папка vendor нужна для таскания с собой внешних зависимостей и особым образом обрабатывается при обработке import.

Goland просто отражает эту особенность - показывая код в папках vendor как внешние зависимости.

Comment: И что же сне делать когда все мои проекты из-за этого покоробило ?

Comment: переименовывать папки vendor во что-то другое, например в vend. Я думаю что для папок vendor будут возникать проблемы и с другими инструментами, которые тоже будут их просто игнорировать, т.к. по мнению инструментов это будет не ваш код, а зависимость, которую нужно просто оставить как есть.

Еще как костыль - сделать симлинки. Т.е. есть папка vendor, а рядом на неё симлинк - чтобы не ломать уже существующие инструменты/пути. Но тут тоже могут быть проблемы из-за того что фактически код в структуре будет дважды присутствовать.